# How to limit for loop iterations within cursor?

Tags: python, cursor, arcpy

I am using a `for` loop within a [SearchCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000) to iterate through features in a featureclass.

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\featureclass'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["fieldA", "FieldB", "FieldC"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # Do something...
```

I am currently troubleshooting the script and need to find a way to limit the iterations to, say, 5 rather than 3500 as it is currently configured.  I know the most basic way to limit the number of iterations in a `for` loop is as follows:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in numbers[0:2]
     print i
```

However, this approach does not work when iterating over a cursor object.  What method can I use to limit the number of iterations of a `for` loop within a cursor object wrapped in a `with` statement?

Comment: Does the cursor have a next() function?

Comment: @RohitJ The `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` does not require a `next()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a counter and a logical statement to limit the number of iterations.  For example:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\featureclass'

count = 1 # Start a counter

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["fieldA", "FieldB", "FieldC"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # Do something...
        if count >= 2:
            print "Processing stopped because iterations >= 2"
            sys.exit()

        count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension to grab everything and then take only the first five rows that you need.  Check the example below:

```
max = 5 #insert max number of iterations here
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["fieldA", "FieldB", "FieldC"]) as cursor:
    output = [list(row) for row in cursor][:max]
```

It is important to note that each row is a tuple output, thus the list() method is used to create a 2d list that can be used for whatever you need.  Even if your dataset is 3500 rows, this should do the trick in little time.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way:

```
for index, row in enumerate(cursor):
  if index > x:
    # do something...
  else:
    # do something...
```